# TableView cells are blurry

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im having an interesting issue in viewing cells in tableview:
 At first when the tableview is loaded the cells look a bit blurry, the weird thing is that when showing and then hiding the keyboard they'll be fixed till sliding the table again (dequeuing new cells).
[image: Before]

[image: After]

In general there are 3 types of cells in that tableview (CustomCellWithButton,     AddSlidesCells and CustomCell). the blurry can be found in all of them but it is clearly     seen in CustomCell. It is making me crazzzzy :S  Please Help

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier;
 if((indexPath.section == 4 && (indexPath.row == 1)))
 {
    CellIdentifier = @"CustomCellWithButton";
    CustomCellWithButton *cell = (CustomCellWithButton*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellWithButton" owner:nil options:nil];

        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell = (CustomCellWithButton *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(nextButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

    return cell;
}
else
{
    if((indexPath.section == 3 && (indexPath.row == 0))){
        CellIdentifier = @"AddSlidesCells";

        AddSlidesCells *cell = (AddSlidesCells*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AddSlidesCells" owner:nil options:nil];

            for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
                if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                    cell = (AddSlidesCells *)currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        [cell.switchButton setOn:[self getswitchButtonsStatesByIndexPath:indexPath] withIndexpath:indexPath];
        [cell.switchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:forEvent:) 
                    forControlEvents:(UIControlEventValueChanged | UIControlEventTouchDragInside)];
        [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(addSlicePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        NSLog(@" ---- here add to dismiss keyboared");

        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

        if (alignedLeft) {
            [cell hardAllignToLeft];

        }else
            [cell hardAllignToRight];

        return cell;
    }

    else
    {
        CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
        BOOL dequed;
        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        NSString* placeHolder = [self getplaceHoldersByIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell == nil) {
            dequed = NO;
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];

            for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
                if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                    cell = (CustomCell *)currentObject;
                    [cell setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];

                    break;
                }
            }
        }else
            dequed = YES;

        cell.alignedLeft = alignedLeft;

        [cell.textField setPlaceholder:placeHolder];
        [cell.textField setText:[self getTextfieldByIndexPath:indexPath] andIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.switchButton setOn:[self getswitchButtonsStatesByIndexPath:indexPath] withIndexpath:indexPath];
        [cell.switchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:forEvent:)
                    forControlEvents:(UIControlEventValueChanged | UIControlEventTouchDragInside)];
        [cell.textField  addTarget:self action:@selector(UIControlEventEditingChanged:) 
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        cell.textField.delegate = self;

        if( [placeHolder isEqualToString:[OperationsOnCoreData PlistCommonStrings:@"Telephone"]] ||
           [placeHolder isEqualToString:[OperationsOnCoreData PlistCommonStrings:@"Email"]]){

            cell.plusSignButton.hidden = NO;
            cell.minusSignButton.hidden = YES;
            [cell.plusSignButton addTarget:self action:@selector(plusSignButtonPressed:)
                          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
        else
            if(( !([placeHolder rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",[OperationsOnCoreData PlistCommonStrings:@"Telephone"]]].location == NSNotFound)||
                !([placeHolder rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",[OperationsOnCoreData PlistCommonStrings:@"Email"]]].location == NSNotFound))){

                cell.minusSignButton.hidden = NO;
                cell.plusSignButton.hidden = YES;
                [cell.minusSignButton addTarget:self action:@selector(minusSignButtonPressed:) 
                               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            }
            else{
                cell.minusSignButton.hidden = YES;
                cell.plusSignButton.hidden = YES;                            
            }


        if(cell.switchButton.on){
            [cell.textField setEnabled:YES];
            cell.textField.alpha = 1; 
        }else{
            [cell.textField setEnabled:NO];
            cell.textField.alpha = 0.5;
            cell.plusSignButton.enabled = NO;
            cell.minusSignButton.enabled = NO;
        }

        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];  

        if (alignedLeft) {
                [cell hardAllignToLeft];

        }else
                [cell hardAllignToRight];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please show your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by blurry, but this is an interesting problem, I'm following up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blurry cells look blurry because the elements are one pixel less high than the non-blurry ones. So the blurry look is caused by the resizing of the switch button and the plus icon.

To fix it, you'll need to investigate the layout of your cell, in particular how these elements sized. They probably should always take their natural size. The pasted code doesn't contain the relevant parts.

Comment: You maybe right, but how can you explain the fact that the switch button cannot be sized... it is persisted to its normal size.

Comment: It's a bit strange indeed. But the switch button can be resized. It's just the interface builder that won't let you do it. How did you create the table cell views? With IB or code? Can you either describe their structure and the relevant sizing attributes or show the code?

Comment: CustomCell which implements UITableViewCell with a xib, textField/switch/plus button added as subviews in Interface Builder. Simple.

Comment: What's the exact view hierarchy? What are the view mode, alignments and autosizing attribute of each element? (In general, try to set the view mode to something else than "Scale To Fill".)

Comment: The hierarchy is: UITableViewCell includes UITextField and UISwitch.  I tried few View Modes and it didn't help :S    Tried Authorize on/off for each element and didn't help.  It is so strange... the best part is that everything become ok when the keyboard appear, does it refreshes the screen (in the HW level)??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can define your cell identifier as `static` and then change it with each call. You should define three static string variables (one for each type) then use the appropriate variable in each case. I'm wondering if this is preventing your cells from dequeuing properly, or from being added to the table with the wrong identifier.

Normally the blurry issues are when you are adding subviews to the cell in the wrong place (ie not when you are first initialising the cell) but that doesn't seem to be the case here. However you are doing a lot of operations (setting actions etc) that don't appear to change per row, so these would be better done inside your cell==nil statement.

Comment: No one of these helped, I'm getting crazy... in interface builder I moved the textfield and switch button, but it doesn't help, wherever I place them they'll be cut. When I tap the textfield comes up the keyboard and the problem fixed till the next dequeue :S

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about the problem, I have to say I cant see any blurring in your screenshots above, what do you mean by 'cut' in your comment?

Comment: Also, why are you setting the frame of customCell? Isn't the frame correct in the nib?

Comment: you right, I removed this part and nothing changed (looks like I was trying to resolve the problem there).